# Android Kotlin How to Access ImageView in Layout From Separate Activity File

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using `android studio 4.1.1` and `kotlin`

I'm using a `recyclerView` to show a list of exercise records (items) in a `ScrollView`.  In my xml layout, `weight_item.xml`, I have the layout of how item is displayed in the list.  In this layout I have an `ImageView` that shows an edit-icon.  When clicked, I want to process that click in my `DisplayWeightsActivity` activity.

The list of items shows in my `DisplayWeightsActivity` activity.  I'm not sure, but "I think" I want to process the `setOnClickListener` for my `ImageView` in this Activity. It is the one that shows when the click happens. But when I create a reference to the ImageView in this Activity, I get an error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.ImageView`

My Code:

```
weigh_item.xml

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit" />
```

```
DisplayWeightsActivity.kt

...
var listEdit = findViewById(R.id.listEdit) as ImageView // error on this line
...
```

If this makes sense to you, Am I doing this correctly?  How can I access the `ImageView` from my `DisplayWeightsActivity` ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can't access a view not present in its corresponding xml file and for your use case, add an `onclicklistener` to the image view in the `onbindviewholder` method of your adapter class

Comment: Is the ``RecyclerView`` being displayed in ``DisplayWeightsActivity``? Generally you'll handle setting up click listeners in the RecyclerView's ``Adapter``(in ``onBindViewHolder`` when the ``ViewHolder`` with the ``ImageView`` is set up for a particular item) and they can call a function on the activity to do a whatever

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my `recyclerView` is in my `activity_display_weights.xml` layout.  I will try doing this in the `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: How do I set up a click listener in my Adapter?  Inside `onBindViewHolder` and/or `onCreateViewHolder` does not like `findViewById`

Comment: Call `findViewById` on the parent ViewGroup of the inflated layout.